# Two-line status line in Vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to have two lined status line in Vim? In some cases (not always), I would like to display a second line for additional information. How is it possible to reach in Vim?

Comment: But if you use a wide terminal (or stretch out the GUI) you can fit more info on the one status line.

Comment: Maybe one of this answers will help: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27337/is-it-possible-to-get-vim-airline-to-make-the-statusline-2-or-more-lines-high https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986884/can-i-have-multiline-statusline-in-vim

Answer (score 1):

From what I know: not possible.

Comment: sad news if that's true.

Comment: akira is correct, it is not possible. It has been discussed before on the Vim Developers' mailing list on occasion, but as far as I recall the conclusion was that it would require too much effort to change the code for a feature that not enough people want.

Bram does tend to accept patches that have been thoroughly tested and conform to the Vim coding style, so if you want it badly enough and you know C, you can try implementing it and submitting it.

Comment: You might try writing a plugin or something in vimscript that displays the extra details in the preview window or an extra split buffer.  If you specify some of the details of the info you want I'm sure someone on here would probably give you enough info to get you most of the way there.